# mogrify with caption (imagemagick or graphicsmagick)

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to do several actions on an image (resize, crop, add some blank white space on bottom).

Then I'm trying to add a caption in that empty white space.

I want to use `mogrify` so I can edit the existing file, rather than creating a new file (it will be in high volume).

This is giving me an error, I'm not quite sure how to do this. It does work with `convert` though.

```
magick mogrify -resize 300x -crop 300x200+0+50 -extent 300x290 input.jpg -size 300x90 -gravity SouthWest -font "Arial" -pointsize 24 -fill black caption:'dis some really long shit that goes on 3 lines onmg how will it ever the' -composite -quality 100
```

Comment: You cannot do composite operations in mogrify that way. The only way is to pre-create the extra text caption image and then use -draw to do the composite. You will need to loop over each image and process it with magick (in place of convert) and save over the input as the output with the same name. Mogrify processes each image separately and does not allow multi-image operations such as composite. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose. In place of caption and composite, you could use -draw or -annotate to insert your text.

Comment: hmm i see.. but what if i need line breaks automatically/ That was my main reason for using caption. Also what is the differecne between `magick` and `convert`? I set the output filename to be the same as the input name (replace output.jpg with input.jpg above) and it seems to work, but im not sure if theres some side effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

magick is for IM 7 and convert is for IM 6. If you need to do mogrify, then you must prepare the text image in a separate command and save it. Then use -draw in mogrify to do the composite. But if you are processing only one image at a time, then convert is the more flexible option and will allow compound statements and composite. Mogrify does not allow both input and output images. It takes an asterix wild card (or one file) and processes it writing the output over the input, unless you provide an output directory. See the links I mentioned in my last comment.

Here are 3 ways to do it. The first two use magick on IM 7 and the third creates a text image using magick and then uses magick mogrify to composite it using -draw. I recommend that you use the second method and if you have many images to process, then write a script loop over each input image.

Input:

[image]

**This uses composite:**

```
magick lena.jpg -resize 300x -crop 300x200+0+50 +repage -extent 300x290 \( -size 300x90 -gravity SouthWest -font "Arial" -pointsize 24 -fill black caption:'This is some really long stuff that goes on 3 lines so how will it ever fit' \) -compose over -composite -quality 100 lena_result1.jpg
```

[image]

**This is simpler with no extent, just append:**

```
magick lena.jpg -resize 300x -crop 300x200+0+50 +repage \( -size 300x90 -gravity SouthWest -font "Arial" -pointsize 24 -fill black caption:'This is some really long stuff that goes on 3 lines so how will it ever fit' \) -append -quality 100 lena_result2.jpg
```

[image]

**This creates the text image and saves as tmp.png:**

```
magick -size 300x90 -gravity SouthWest -font "Arial" -pointsize 24 -fill black caption:'This is some really long stuff that goes on 3 lines so how will it ever fit' text.png
```

[image]

**Then it uses -draw to composite the test.png image onto the one input to magick mogrify, which is always specified last in the command. The output is written over this input:**

```
magick mogrify -resize 300x -crop 300x200+0+50 +repage -extent 300x290 -draw "gravity southwest image over 0,0 0,0 'text.png'" lena2.jpg
```

[image]

In the above, I have used Unix syntax. For Windows, remove the \ from before ( and before ).

Comment: so awesome, thank you!!! I really appreciate how you wrote the different examples, I was doing this for hours and wasn't really getting anywhere.

Comment: One quick question -- how would I do the first approach but limit the height to 3 lines only (so the text just gets cut off)? Also, if its only 1-2 lines of text (rather than 3), the empty space should be below the text (so the text is closest to the image). thanks again for your help

Comment: With caption: you cannot limit the text to some number of lines. You can however, use label: rather than caption: and put in your own line breaks and limit the text you supply. To put the text right next to the image, it is best to just use append rather than composite. If you then need more space at the bottom, you can use -extent at the end or -splice to add empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry when I say "limit" i dont mean actually limit the text, I just mean limit the size of the caption such that any overflow is simply hidden (so the sentence cuts off at the middle). I will use your first version, but the problem is that if the text is only 2 lines it doesnt but up against the bottom of image (with white space on bottom), it puts the white space above the text (so the text goes to very bottom of canvas). My goal is the text always starts under the image whether its 1,2,3 lines, and if its 4 lines it just gets cut off

Comment: Actually it works perfect if I change your 'only append' method to NorthWest, I just would like to give it an extra 5px of space under the image and its perfect! I tried using geometry +0+5 but no dice

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous request about spacing. Gravity northwest in the text command is correct to start it at the top left. To add space replace between the image and text replace -append with -smush +5. Smush is like -append, but allows both positive or negative adjustments. Negative would overlap. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#smush. I still do not understand how you would make the text cut off at two lines. Please show how you did that if it actually works

Comment: The only way I know to make it do only two lines is to get the font glyph metric information using -debug annotate and then compute the size of the area you want for two lines and then crop it after making the text image. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#font_info. Also note, you can use -trim +repage when creating the text image to remove the extra space at top and bottom before appending (or smushing).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for `smush`. As for the text cutting off, you already are doing it, and it works perfect. If you type a bunch of text longer than 3 lines, it will stop at the height of 3 lines, and the text overflow will be hidden. I believe it comes from this `300x90` size

Comment: That does not work for me to cut the text off. Please show your exact code and input and output images. See my new answer to cut 3 lines into only 2 lines. And identify your ImageMagick version and platform.

Comment: `ImageMagick 7.0.8-50 Q16 x86_64 2019-06-25`

Comment: Your second example produces 2 lines only since your second text is shorter. So 2 lines is all that is needed for pointsize 24 and the height specified. It does not take the longer text and limit it to 2 lines. By specifying width and height and pointsize, you are actually limiting the text at pointsize 24 to the height specified. So if you have more text lines than the height, the text will get trimmed to fewer characters than you provided, as per example one. Is that what you were asking? If you remove the height from the command then it will fill all the text to whatever height is needed.

Comment: well I was just saying it it works perfect like that (cutting off the text thats extra). sorry if that wasnt clear. How do I use your command to convert to JPG btw? I tried `-format JPG` but it still is saving PNG I think..

Comment: Which command? My commands all save as resultX.jpg, so output is jpg. The jpg suffix is all that is needed? Do you see JPG or JPEG listed under Delegates when you do `magick -version`. If not, then you need to install the libjpeg delegate. What is your platform and how did you install ImageMagick? If from source, then you have to install all your delegates from separately. If from binary, then binaries usually install most needed delegates. See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php. If you are using a Linux distribution, then you need to discuss this with your admin.

Comment: I just realized im writing to a tempfile that doesnt use an extension. is there some other way i can tell it to do JPG? It seems `-format jpg` is not doing anything

Comment: What tempfile? My magick commands do not use a tempfile, only the magick mogrify. **If you want to continue this, then move this discussion to the chat room**.

Comment: I just mean the code I'm writing to use magick from command line uses a tempfile which by default doesnt have an extension, so when i was passing that path to magick it was not properly understanding the output format. Thanks again for your help, you have been very very helpful :)

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 , sorry i deleted my question by mistake, do you have any idea on how to append text.png to a gif? i did it but the output shows frames of the gif

Comment: Please make a new question and explain in more detail and with your input image and input gif. Is the gif animated?  Do you want the text below the gif as before? Is this for multiple gifs or just one? If the gif is animated or if you want the text above, your best approach would be to write a script loop over each gif you want to use and then use -append to add the text image above or below the gif image. If the gif is animated, then more complex solutions are needed. So please explain in detail and provide example images.

Answer (score 5):

magick is the new name for convert in V7. Presumably to avoid the problem with the Windows built in convert program

Note: Creates the caption as a separate image in memory and joins it to the original image.

Old convert program showing a way to use the image in a variable using php

```
$size = getimagesize( $input ); 
$cmd = " $input ( -size {$size[0]}x30". 
" -background black -fill white". 
" -pointsize 16 -gravity center". 
" caption:\"Caption\" -flatten ) -append "; 
exec("convert $cmd caption_size.jpg");
```

Example using magick - note shortcut in -size which save getting the image size into a variable. One off using Windows

```
magick "input.jpeg" ( -size "fx:w"x30 -background black -fill white -pointsize 30 -gravity center caption:"Caption" -flatten ) -append "output.jpg"
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using ImageMagick to limit the text to 2 of 3 lines. But you have to know that it would have been 3 lines.

I get the width and height of the text image after trimming and then crop it to 2/3 height. Note that I have used -smush +5 to add space between the image and text rather than -append.

Input:

[image]

```
magick lena.jpg -resize 300x -crop 300x200+0+50 +repage \( -size 300x90 -gravity NorthWest -font "Arial" -pointsize 24 -fill black caption:'This is some really long stuff that goes on 3 lines so how will it ever fit' -trim +repage -set option:WxH "%wx%[fx:round(h*2/3)]" -crop "%[WxH]+0+0" +repage \) -smush +5 -quality 100 lena_result2.jpg
```

[image]